# Do not retrieve all columns with Elastic search query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, query-builder

I have an Elastic search query and I would like to retrieve a certain column, not all.

I make my request in java with BoolQUEryBuilder which gives:

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = boolQuery();
query.must(wildcardQuery('value', value + "*"));
return findAll(query);
```

The method findAll :

```
protected List<T> findAll(final BoolQueryBuilder query) {
    Query searchQuery = (new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()).withQuery(query).build();
    SearchHits<T> searchHits = this.elasticsearchRestTemplate.search(searchQuery, this.getClazz(), this.elasticsearchRestTemplate.getIndexCoordinatesFor(this.getClazz()));
    return (List)SearchHitSupport.unwrapSearchHits(searchHits);
}
```

I would like to add a filter on the columns. To illustrate in SQL this gives:

```
Select column_one, column_two from table;
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `findAll()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spring Data Elasticsearch, you should try this instead:

```
...

//include only specific fields
final SourceFilter sourceFilter = new FetchSourceFilter(new String[]{"column_one", "column_two"}, null);

// assemble the query
Query searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(query).build();        
searchQuery.addSourceFilter(sourceFilter);

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search.html#_source_filtering) to fetch only few fields from Elasticsearch query results.

As explained in the same document example below code shows which fields to include and which to exclude.

```
String[] includeFields = new String[] {"title", "innerObject.*"};
String[] excludeFields = new String[] {"user"};
sourceBuilder.fetchSource(includeFields, excludeFields);
```